# Match multi-line pattern in Charles proxy rewrite rule

Tags: proxy, regex

In Charles proxy, I'm trying to use a rewrite rule to match a pattern that spans three lines in a response body, using `\s*` in the Match value (with 'Regex' checked) to match new lines.

It appears that Charles won't match a pattern across several lines, but I haven't been able to confirm that in the Charles documentation. Can anyone confirm one way or the other whether Charles rewrite rules can match patterns across more than one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that you can do this generically, but I came up with this that works for specific newline cases:

```
"group":.*[\n\r]*.*".*"
```

In short, if you explicitly flag the newline in a character class, it can be consumed within the pattern.  Wildcard matchers like `.` and buffer boundaries like `^` and `$` don't.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to accomplish multiline search in Charles via the following:

[\s\S]*

For instance, let's say there is an xml document and I want to start a search at a knownNodeName and continue searching until a @knownAttribute is found n lines below the knownNodeName

The regex pattern in Charles would be:

knownNodeName>[\s\S]*knownAttributeNLineBelow

This works!

If you want to make it a little more complex and actually capture something from the attribute and re-insert it into the document (this was my endgoal), you can accomplish it via following in Charles:

Match Value: 
    knownNodeName>([\s\S]*knownAttributeNLineBelow=")(\w+)

Replace Value:
    knownNodeName> newNode @attr=$2 />$1$2